# how to make a scrollable window in vc++ win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

basically I have a scrollbar in a custom window where we could add other controls like buttons, textboxes and so and so forth, now here is the problem I have created the scrollbar alright it scrolls down and up, but the problem is that the maximum scroll should be specified which then blocks it to scroll more than that, but there could be as much control as the user want, which for me it would not be known, I mean like to tell the problem to be more like a textbox's built-in scroll bar when you specify it with WM_VSCROLL OR HSCROLL, and then give the user the ability to scroll as much as you type on the textbox, that's exactly what I want.
here is the code so far I have been able to go through:-

Code for Scrollbar:-

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
            SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_POS;
            si.nPos = 0;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);
            break;
    }
     case WM_VSCROLL:
    {
            auto action = LOWORD(wParam);
            HWND hScroll = (HWND)lParam;
            int pos = -1;
            if (action == SB_THUMBPOSITION || action == SB_THUMBTRACK) {
                    pos = HIWORD(wParam);
            } else if (action == SB_LINEDOWN) {
                    pos = g_scrollY + 50;
            } else if (action == SB_LINEUP) {
                    pos = g_scrollY - 50;
            } else if (action == SB_PAGEUP) {
                    GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
                    pos = g_scrollY - r.bottom;
            } else if (action == SB_PAGEDOWN){
                    GetClientRect(hwnd, &r);
                    pos = g_scrollY + r.bottom;
            }
            if (pos == -1)
                    break;
            SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_POS;
            si.nPos = pos;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);

            GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);
            pos = si.nPos;
            POINT pt;
            pt.x = 0;
            pt.y = pos - g_scrollY;
            auto hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            LPtoDP(hdc, &pt, 1);
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, -pt.y, NULL, NULL);
            g_scrollY = pos;
            return 0;
    }
case WM_SIZE:
    {
            RECT rc = { 0 };
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
            SCROLLINFO si = { 0 };
            si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
            si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nMax = MAX_RANGE;
            if(si.nPos > 100)
                si.nMax = 5000;
            if(SB_THUMBPOSITION == 100){

                si.nMax = MAX_RANGE;}
            si.nPage = (rc.bottom - rc.top);
            si.nPos = 0;
            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, true);
            break;
    }
```

as you can see si.nMax value is the maximum amount of lines it is going to be able to scroll, but I want it to be as much as there are controls.

Comment: You may want to consider using a GUI framework like wxWidgets, Qt, etc.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: wxWidgets may just barely be usable. Qt, on the other hand, is so broken, that you cannot possibly want to recommend it. Even MFC produces better GUIs, and that's saying a lot. Besides that, the question is about Windows API programming, and a scrollable window is certainly not the reason to go looking for a framework.

Comment: If asking for a framework recommendation is off-topic for SO then suggesting them should be as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must know how many controls are in your window, so you can set nMax member in the SCROLLINFO structure to whatever value you want and call SetScrollInfo() whenever new controls are added.

Comment: ok, how are you going to figure out, how many pictures would a user have to display it in static control on that custom window.

Comment: @alasenburgers: By applying mathematics.

Comment: i am really bad at mathematics but I think I kind of have another idea, i mean like you could tell me to extend the si.nMax value, like if user scrolled up to end the si.nMax value should extend or something

Comment: or we could get the position of last control and set the Max value to that much, i defiantly can't do it without your help

Comment: hey can anybody tell me how to extend it, aye?

Comment: hey is there a button to delete or unsubscribe my account from this website?